# Matlab function input problem, can only see 1 root but supposed to see 2 – Noob question

Tags: functions, roots, matlab

Thank you for reading this question.

I'm studying numerical methods and I'm using Matlab for the practical parts.

The problem:

I'm supposed to find 2 different roots, y = 0, for positive x, x > 0, with the function below. When I plot it in Matlab I can only see 1. I've checked and changed my code countless times but for the life of me I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Please help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

To clarify, I'm not asking for help with an algorithm, I only need help with what I'm doing wrong with inputing the function in Matlab. Again, I can only see it having 1 root, y = 0, and not 2, which is the start of the actual problem I am to solve.

The function:
$$
f(x) = 98x - \biggl(\frac{x^2 + x + 0.2}{x + 1}\biggr)^9 + 5xe^{-x} = 0
$$

Here is my Matlab code:

```
x = 0:0.001:1000;

y = 98.*x - ((x.^2 + x + 0.2)./(x + 1)).^9 + 5.*x.*exp(-x);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you, regards / euro

Comment: One of the roots is negative? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/agrmgctxpj

Comment: This function has only one postive root.

Comment: @Math-fun, it has two positive roots, although [one of them is incredibly small](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+98x+-+((x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+0.2)%2F(x%2B1))%5E9+%2B+5*x*exp(-x)+%3D+0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the function 
$$f(x) = 98x - \biggl(\frac{x^2 + x +\frac 15}{x + 1}\biggr)^9 + 5xe^{-x} $$ $$f(0)=-\frac{1}{1953125}$$ and more than likely
a very small root can exist.

Expanding as a Taylor series, we have $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{1953125}+\frac{201171839 }{1953125}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, then a solution $$x_{est}=\frac{1}{201171839}\approx 4.97087\times 10^{-9}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the scale you are plotting at is preventing you from seeing the solution. Try this code

```
x = -.5:0.001:2;
y = 98.*x-((x.^2+x+ 0.2)./(x+1)).^9 + 5.*x.*exp(-x);
figure;plot(x,y);
grid;
```

Comment: +1.  One of the positive roots is [approximately $4.97087 \times 10^{-9}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+98x+-+((x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+0.2)%2F(x%2B1))%5E9+%2B+5*x*exp(-x)+%3D+0), so setting the minimum $x$ at $0.001$ as OP did will result in this root not being displayed.

Comment: @tilper Thanks for the edit, I haven't figured out how to do separate lines like that and I can't see what you did when I click on 'edit'. What's the magic code for  new line?

Comment: @tilper re: the positive root near zero; that should be determined by an iteration, or the Matlab function *fzero*. I'm sure you know better than to rely on what you can see on a graph anyway.

Comment: Indenting four spaces at the beginning of the line will put the line in `code form`.  I don't understand your second comment since my original comment was just highlighting the point you made in your answer by explicitly saying why OP's scale was preventing OP from seeing the other root; I wasn't suggesting the graph should be used to determine the root's value.

Comment: @tilper Thanks for the information and apologies for the other confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late update, been busy.

Thank you very much for the input on my problem. You are correct, the scale and step-size I was using was the culprit.

Using this revised code shows that there is indeed a small positive root very close to x = 0.

```
x = -0.001:1*exp(-10):0.001;
y = 98.*x-((x.^2+x+ 0.2)./(x+1)).^9 + 5.*x.*exp(-x);

figure;plot(x,y);
grid;

axis([ 0.0000000045 0.0000000055 -0.00000001 0.00000001])
```

Again, thank you very much, regards / euro